# pymongo does not create new database (mongo is running on a docker)

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, pymongo

I use docker-compose to start mongo on my local computer with a username and password. It looks running OK.

Then I run a python script, import pymongo to create a database. There's no error sending out. However, the new database is not created at all.

My **docker-compose.yml** script is as below

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongodb
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:0.54
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb-data:/data/db
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Part of my **python** script is as below

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
dbclient = MongoClient(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/",
    username = 'mongodb',
    password = 'mongodb'
)
appdb = dbclient['blog']
print(dbclient.list_database_names())
```

The shell output is only the system mongo's databases

```
['admin', 'config', 'local']
```

Can any one point out what I need to do to fix? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to write something to the db before it will be saved.

Comment: wow, thank you. I am a newbie in mongo. Looks quite different from mysql in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, Add collection & some test data, Should work. Mongo doesn't  create database without collection & data.

```
appdb = dbclient["blog"]
appcoll = appdb["blogcollection"]
document = {"user_id": 1, "user": "test"}
appcoll.insert_one(document)
```